# Is there a C# element like 'THotKey' in Delphi?

Tags: c#, winforms, hotkeys

I'm looking for a form element in *C#* like the `THotKey` in *Delphi*
It looks like a `TextBox` but it's input is a keystroke, instead text.

I don't really know how to explain it so here are some visual examples:

[image]

[image]
Basically, it catches the key press or key combo.

Does such element already exist in C#?
Or do I have to make it myself out of `TextBox`?

Comment: you mean TextBox for hotkey?

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel
Yeah.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Framework doesn't provide one. Take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15085/A-simple-hotkey-selection-control-for-NET) Article in CodeProject.
I have used it sometime before.